# Mysql select month included into 2 months

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a simple query to have a month included into 2 months. I explain:

I've a table with

```
id | month1 | month2
```

Than means id is ok from month1 to month2 (the fields are month numbers) . For example:

```
145 | 8 | 2
```

Means : id 2 is ok from August to february

Now I'm looking for a simple query to select id when I choose one month. For example:

For month March (so number 3), which Id are concerned?

I've made some very long query with a lot of AND and OR but it is very complicated, I'm sure there is a simple way to have it. The difficulty is the ids between one month X and an other after december...

A query like

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 2 between month(month1) and month(month2)
```

Any idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return all records that are active for a given month:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE CASE WHEN month1 < month2
           THEN (month1 <= 3 AND month2 >= 3)
      ELSE (month1 <= 3)
           OR
           (month1 > 3 AND month2 >= 3)
      END CASE
```

I'd try something along these lines, although above query has not been tested. (I can't seem to get on sqlfiddle...)

The `CASE` test whether or not the first month is smaller than the second month, in which case it's easy: you just test for the given number to be between `month1` and `month2`. If it's not, you should provide two options: either your selection is greater than `month1`, so it should always return true; or it's smaller than `month1`, but in that case it should be greater or equal to `month2`.

Comment: END was missing. I've tested it and it seems to work: all records returned are the one where March is included!
Please edit your answer that I can validate it ;-) Thanks

Comment: Sorry 'bout that. Was setting up my own test db, since sqlfiddle is down. Good thing you found it!

Answer (score 0):

The following query will output all rows which are in two individually months.

SELECT *, COUNT(1) AS amountOfMonths FROM table GROUP BY month HAVING amountOfMonths = 2

Comment: Doens't work, you have 2 fields "month" : month1 and month2 in the table. The request have to be "select xxx from table where 2 is between month1 column and month2 column